# xml is not transformed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, babeljs

I am new to node.js and reactjs. I have the below index.js file as the entry point of my small application which I need to be transpiled.

I am using webpack and I have the below package.json.

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { hello, goodbye } from './lib'

render(
     <div>
        {hello} 
        {goodbye}
     </div>
    ,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

**package.json**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: "dist/assets",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist',
        port: 3000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["latest", "stage-0", "react"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I try to build, I get the below error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: /home/mike/Desktop/Exercise_Files/Ch02/02_06/start/src/index.js Unexpected token (6:2)
```

The folder structure is as below:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── bundle.js
│   ├── bundle.js.map
│   ├── index.html
│   └── main.js
├── node_module(+)
├── out.txt
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.bbl.js
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

**EDIT**

I understand the error is saying it can't compile the < jsx syntax. But, actually this code is part of an online course and it has webpack.config.js file which DOES transpile the jsx but I am not sure which part of the below working webpack.config.js is actually doing it.

**Working webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: "dist/assets",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist',
        port: 3000
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ["babel-loader"],
                query: {
                    presets: ["latest", "stage-0", "react"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DJA-PiJkI8TTW3u7fhjS9AsgY-g9M5y3/view?usp=sharing) is the code with the issue described above.

Please let me know if you have any clue on this.

Thank you

Comment: What are hello and good bye?

Comment: @RohithMurali this is not important, because the error is not a ```TypeError: hello is not defined```. The error is ```Unexpected token``` at 6:2, which reffers to ```<```, so the problem is that transpiler is not expect the JSX in the code.

Comment: To verify that, did you simply try `render(<div>test</div>,document.getElementById('react-container'))`

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance Imbalance, I agree but what is the fix??

Comment: @RohithMurali I did and it still complains about the open angle bracket.

Comment: @MikeITExpert I already answered, did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your babel's config query like this:

```
...
query: {
    presets: ["latest", "stage-0", "react"],
    plugins: ["transform-react-jsx"]
}
...
```

I can share you my own config, but it's pretty weird :D

Obviously, you should first install it via `npm`.
More information you can get [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) :)

Comment: I agree I am missing jsx transpiler but the the plugin tag is for .babelrc file, however, I am using webpack.config.js. I think I need a sort of jsx loader thing. If I add your code I get: ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: /home/mike/Desktop/Exercise_Files/Ch02/02_06/start/src/index.js Unexpected token (6:2)

Comment: @MikeITExpert try then ```test: /\.(jsx|js)$/``` instead of yours

Comment: no luck yet. :-( Just curious What are the presets for ?

Comment: I have the working code from a an online course [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JLGRjJ4XV7GYUQ2PyGfjOosDIhTlBT4M/view?usp=sharing) I just don't understand why it is working but not mine.

Comment: @MikeITExpert well, babel from the box transpiles plain js. JSX is a custom syntax, so babel should include some plugin to transform it to plain js an then transpile it:) Plugins are for detecting, what features should be transpiled. Also have to ask, did you relaunch webpack dev server after changing config?

Comment: I have package.json (edited the question) file which working just fine and it takes care of the jsx too. I just can't find out which part is takes care of transpiling the jsx.

Comment: Its pretty weird if it doesn't work. Sadly, but I can check it by myself only on Monday

Comment: @MikeITExpert babel loader actually does the jsx transpilation, but you have no jsx files in your project yet. And i suppose, you shared wrong package.json content)

Comment: I added a working webpack.coinfig.js to the question **I just don't understand if babel does the jsx transform why the same webpack.conig.js is not working for me.**. My webpack.conig.js and the working one are exactly identical but give my folder structure my code is not build which means that there must be sth wrong with my code / folder structure. @LevitatorImbalance